# populating data in combo box

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

Please be easy with me, I am trying to solve but could not hence asking for help. I have 2 combo boxes named as first combo box and second combo box in auto.jsp.

I am getting value in a div in auto.jsp by onchange event of first combo box, but the value, i am getting is not populating in the second combo box rather it is being displayed like plain text inside the `id combo2`. How to populate this data with in that second combo box. I tried a lot but could not do it , any ideas please?

### **auto.jsp**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#combo1").change(function() {
            $.get('combo.jsp', { combo1Val : $(this).val() }, function(responseData) {
                $("#combo2").replaceWith(responseData);
            });
        });
    });          
</script>

<body>
    <select id="combo1" name="combo1Val">// After onchange event of this combo box, second box is disappeared and i am getting value 1, how can i display this one inside the option value of second combo box?
        <option value="">select</option>
        <option value="1">One</option>//
    </select>

    <select id="combo2" name="combo2">
        <option value="">select</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
    </select>
</body>
```

### **combo.jsp**

```
<% 
    String combo1Val=request.getParameter("comboVal");
    out.println(combo1Val);// displaying value 1 in auto.jsp in id combo2
%>
```

Any ideas please?

Comment: When I suggested using `.replaceWith()` in an answer to one of your other questions, I explicitly mentioned that your jsp needed to return _all_ of the html for a `<select>` element so that the old `<select>` would be replaced with the new one (I gave an example of the html too). I believed the intention was for selection of a value in the first combo to repopulate the entire list in the second. So if you return a simple string then of course `.replaceWith()` is going to replace the whole combo with that string. Are you saying you just want to add one option to the existing options in combo2?

Comment: @nnnnnn, ya i want to populate that value 1 inside second combo box in an option, not by replacing the entire combo box, can you please give me an answer

Comment: append? how can i populate value 1 in that second combobox?

Comment: @Rory McCrossan..can you please give me an idea , how can it be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing this line:

```
$("#combo2").replaceWith(responseData);
```

With something like this:

```
$("#combo2").append(
   $("<option></option>").html(responseData).val(responseData)
);
```

That should add a new option to the end of the second combo, where both the display text and the `value` attribute will be set to `responseData` (since you're not returning separate values for those).

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/primers/jsp/

Comment: it worked, can you please tell me how you are knowing all these things but why these things are not entering into my brain?

Comment: that link is telling "page not found"

Comment: My apologies, I didn't notice that the question had been deleted (I assume I can still see it because I have enough rep-points). Try http://www.htmlgoodies.com/primers/jsp/

Comment: ya good one by the way i am getting ready to ask one new question

Comment: "Nurse, cancel my one o'clock."

Comment: please have a look at this question and please give me a solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9238267/clean-old-options-from-child-combo-box-when-receiving-data-by-json-array-objects