# populating child combo box in javascript after getting data in JSON array objects

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, combobox

I tried, googled a lot but still finding for a solution. My problem is simple just i want to populate child combo box in index.jsp after an onchange event in parent combo box. I have used JSON array objects to retrieve but not populating child combo, any help please?
When i select `ABC` then automatically `001` will be populated in second combo box, similarly when i select `PQR` then `002` will be populated and `001` will be removed.

### **index.jsp**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $("#combobox1").change(function() {// by onchange event in parent combo box i want to populate 
 child combobox 
$.getJSON('state.jsp', {count : this.value}, function(responseData) {
$("#combobox2").append(
$("<option></option>").html(responseData.name).val(responseData.name)
);
});
});
});          
</script>

 <body>  
//parent combo box
<select id="combobox1" name="count">
<option value="abc">ABC</option>
<option value="pqr">PQR</option>
</select>
 // child combo box

<select id="combobox2" name="combobox2">// here i want to populate data `001` by `ABC` or `002` by selecting `PQR` , how can i do it?
<option value="">select</option>
</body>
```

### **state.jsp**

```
 <%@page import="net.sf.json.JSONObject"%>
 <%@page import="net.sf.json.JSONArray"%>
 <%
 String count=request.getParameter("count");
 if(count.equals("ABC"){
 JSONObject arrayObj= new JSONObject();
   arrayObj.put("name","001");// how to populate `001` in an option in child combo box when `ABC` will be selected in parent combo?
  response.setContentType("application/json");
  response.getWriter().write(arrayObj.toString());
}
else if (count.equals("PQR"){
 JSONObject arrayObj= new JSONObject();
arrayObj.put("name","002");// how to populate `002` in an option in child combo box when `PQR` will be selected in parent combo?
  response.setContentType("application/json");
  response.getWriter().write(arrayObj.toString());
}
%>
```

Comment: You aren't using jquery, so why tag it that way?  On a side note, using jQuery would make your life a lot easier.

Comment: i have tried with jquery by seeing examples here, but it does not trigger immediately after onchange in parent combo, i have to select from that drop down menus

Comment: Can you post your jQuery examples?

Comment: i have edited my question, please see and suggest any idea

Comment: Is this some homework, cos this is the second, almost identical, use of this I've seen today.

Comment: i have taken all codes from this forum http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9238267/clean-old-options-from-child-combo-box-when-receiving-data-by-json-array-objects are you talking about this?

Comment: i slightly modified and posted but your answer in that forum did not work for me hence i asked

Comment: The error is likely in your JSP then, as the jQuery and Javascript is sound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using my example code provided in [Clean old options from child dropdown when receiving data by JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9238267/clean-old-options-from-child-combo-box-when-receiving-data-by-json-array-objects)

You need to case **insensitive** comparison of the `count` field (as the original poster in the other thread does), as you pass back one of the following values:

- abc
- pqr

and you are checking for:

- ABC
- PQR

What you are looking for never exists, so you will never return any data for the second combo.